# blogspot : syntax highligting URLs are replaced to https from http

Tags: blogs, syntaxhighlighter

Background : 
I am using CustomizeMe.xml template as my blogger template from helpbolgger.com . I have also integrated syntax highlighter in blogger template.  The CDN file which I have included in the template do not load and give the "net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED" error

e.g. http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shCore.js

When I viewed the source of my post, I found that the URLs for the in the view source are bing "//alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shCore.js" thereby its taking https instead of http. So the error that I get in the console is

GET https://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/styles/shCore.css net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

I am not sure why the URLs are becoming https urls

The code that I have included just above head tag in the template is

```
<!-- Syntax Highlighter Additions START -->
<link href='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/styles/shCore.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<link href='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/styles/shThemeEclipse.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shCore.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushJScript.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushJava.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script src='http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushXml.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
  SyntaxHighlighter.config.bloggerMode = true;
  SyntaxHighlighter.all();
  </script>
<!-- Syntax Highlighter Additions END -->
```

but when I view source of the post then it looks as below..

```
<!-- Syntax Highlighter Additions START -->
<link href="//alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/styles/shCore.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="//alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/styles/shThemeEclipse.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="//alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shCore.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushJScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushJava.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushXml.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
  SyntaxHighlighter.config.bloggerMode = true;
  SyntaxHighlighter.all();
  </script>
<!-- Syntax Highlighter Additions END -->
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Exact same problem here, I tried many things but without success. Hope to get an answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

After some tests, that bug (I think we can call it a bug) only appears for me in "Preview Mode" on blogger.

When the article is published, all is working like a charm.

In fact, it's just annoying that we can't have a preview on that.

I know it's not really an "answer" but I think it can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Some observation by which I could actually resolve the  issue.

When we are creating the post which is not yet posted. 
If you preview preview such post blogger removes the http from URLs and shows only "//alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/styles/shCore.css".

Publish your post and it should work properly.